# Toilet running when using other

Tags: toilet

My upstairs toilet starts running when I turn the tub on or the washing machine on, which is located downstairs

Comment: please explain what this means exactly? `toilet starts running`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. As @jsotola noted, we'll need more information before we can help you.